# In a nunjucks template an embedded javascript variable is not evaluated correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, nunjucks

I have a part of a nunjucks template inside an if that uses an array and a javascript variable that comes from a script.
The code is like this:

```
{% if project.versionNeverReleased.indexOf("${major}") > -1 %}
   ...template code...
{% endif %}
```

project.versionNeverReleased is a nunjkucks array that comes from the global variable `project` and his values are:

```
"versionNeverReleased": ["4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

`major` is a javascript variable that represent the major version of the site:

```
ex: const major = "4"
```

If i use these values in my template the results of the condition is always -1 as if the value of `major` is not a string that has the value of 4.
All the template code is embedded in a function:

```
const blockVersionTemplate = (major, minor, patch) => `
<div>
   {% if project.versionNeverReleased.indexOf("${major}") === -1 %}
      ...template code...
   {% endif %}
</div>
`;
```

There another way to do this so I can work with both variables inside a nujnucks template?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your issue is related to how to works `indexOf` (it uses `===`-comparator)

```
[1, 2, 3].indexOf(2) -> 1
['1', '2', '3'].indexOf(2) -> -1
```

Your version array contains strings, so you should convert `major` to string by `${ major + ''}`.